# DNA ligase mechanism

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, dna

[image]

I am unable to understand what happens to the phosphates from  ATP. What are they used for ?Charging 3' end or 5'end ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ligate two strands of DNA you build up a phosphodiester bond. To do so, you need energy, and this energy for the DNA ligase comes from the ATP (in bacteria this energy can also come from NAD<sup>+</sup>.
The enzyme metabolizes ATP to AMP + PP<sub>i</sub> and binds the AMP in its active center. Then the AMP is involved in the reaction itself and released afterwards. This [page](http://www.biochem.umd.edu/biochem/kahn/molmachines/replication/DNA%20Ligase.htm) has a few illustrations on this process.
If you want to dive really deep into the topic, have a look at this review:

- [Eukaryotic DNA Ligases: Structural and Functional Insights](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.biochem.77.061306.123941)